# Android: Need an advice with "sign out"-button implementation

Tags: android

I need an advice. I need to implement a "sign out"-button in my app. When a user presses it, I should clean my database and open main screen. I just made drop-recreate of all tables in DB. But suddenly I found that if a user clicks sign out while the app is in the process of refreshing the data (parsing-saving it to DB) in another thread, then I get "SQLiteException: no such table". So the question is: how properly implement sign out ? Some of the variants: disable "sign out"-button or not to drop tables until data sync completes ? Or your variants ... ?

I followed the MVP pattern during the app implementation. So, my view (activity/fragment) calls presenter's (it's scoped-singletone provided by dagger2) load-method and the presenter calls an intercator to start data sync. Also it would be great to see your patterns to load a data. As I know somebody prefers to use android services...

TIA

Comment: I wouldn't drop tables, simple delete-all-rows is enough

Comment: according to google's recommendations, the tables should be created/altered inside `SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate/onUpgrade` implementations

Comment: but how to avoid data-duplication ? if I reset an app while a thread which processes data is still working, I delete all rows but the thread will save some data in tables...

Comment: well, you have to ensure that no other thread is running when you start the delete-all process. If you can't than your app is doomed :)

Answer (score 0):

For an Idea ,

1. You can keep a flag in shared preferences as "tabledCleared" .
2. Once user click on sign out, update the value as 0, and then start to clear the tables. If tables clearing was completed, update the value as 1.
3. If clearing was interrupted, value will remain as 0
4. On next loading check the value. If its 0, clear the tables again before re-loading new values.